# Embedded blanks in Google dialogflow service name

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

The service name field in Google Dialogflow will not allow embedded blanks, yet when I view services at https://assistant.google.com/explore/c/12/?hl=en the service names nearly all have embedded blanks.

Where do I specify the name with embedded blanks that will eventually appear in the Google Assistant "explore" directory? (Talk to xxx yyy zzz)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "service name".

The "agent name" is an internal name used by you to refer to the project in Dialogflow.

The "project name" or "project id" is a name used to identify the Google Cloud project that this Dialogflow project is associated with.

You set both of these when you create the project in Dialogflow:

[image: Dialogflow new project]

The "display name", "invocation name", or "action name" are defined as part of the [Actions console](https://console.actions.google.com/) by selecting the "Invocations" menu item on the left

[image: Actions console]

Comment: I guess I mean agent name. My screen does not look like your first one above. Under Agent Name it has a series of tabs: General, Languages, ML Settings etc. I am not using Actions on Google. I am purely using Dialogflow. My project-id was pre-filled and is "api-project-731086205467". To the right of that are two links, Google Cloud then Actions on Google.

Comment: Are you trying to develop for the Assistant? I'm confused.

Comment: Yes, mainly to be activated via Google Home. At this stage just a test app but may add it to Google later if it qualifies.